# Can some help: 'No ending delimiter'

Tags: php, validation, email

Message! 'Warning preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in E:\wamp\form_elements...

```
if(!preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)) {
            echo "Invalid email form Please reenter<br />";}
```

Any suggestions.  I mean if I wasn't new to this maybe I could figure this out, but xq's for my laziness.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: The error message is clear.

Comment: There are easier ways to validate an e-mail, check out `filter_var()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern needs to have a starting and ending delimiter (in this case I've used `~`), see [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match):

```
preg_match("~^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$~", $email);
```

The delimiter is used to mark the beginning & ending of the pattern. After the ending delimiter you can add modifiers such as case insensitive (`i`):

```
$pattern = '~^[a-z]{3,6}$~i';
```

Comment: interesting, I thought the delimiters we always `/`. Does `~` mean something special?

Comment: @andrew Actually, you can use anything you want as far as I know. I like `~` because if you use `/` in the expression you have to escape it.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  But I still not sure what a delimiter is exactly, and the link you added (a document that would take some overnight reading for me to absorb info), I didn't address "this" particular string.  If it did, it must have been buried deeper in the document.  I'll give it a check later.

Answer (score 1):

PCRE expressions need to be escaped to be handled by the preg_* function family. A delimeter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character. You may add specific [modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) after the ending delimeter to change the expressions outcome.

Php-specific documentation is located [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

PHP has better ways to validate an email. Taken from the official docs from filter_var:

```
var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a start and end delimiter to wrap the definition of your regular expression. By convention a forward slash is used at either end, and you should stick to that convention if possible. The only typical exception is if your regular expression contains forward slashes in which case using another character delimiter can help make it more readable and less troublesome. In this instance your statement should look like this:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email)) {
            echo "Invalid email form Please reenter<br />";}
```